# Unknown column "ASDF" in 'field list'... But "ASDF" is a value

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I'm receiving an Error Code 1054. Unknown column 'ASDF' in 'field list'.

However I'm passing 'ASDF' as a value, not as a column!

This is the query I'm using here:

```
INSERT INTO database.table (column1, column2,.....,column84) VALUES (ASDF, value2, value3...., value84)
```

Comment: Put quotes around ASDF if it's a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You column type is most likely a character field.
If you want to insert a string, you have to declare it with surrounding `'` , example : 'ASDF'.
Otherwise MySQL with interpret it as a column.

Comment: Thank you! It was so simple! :( I have a follow up question. I have all these 84 columns that I want to put in the database. Some of them are numbers, some of them are strings, but I don't know which is which. The only solution I have thought about is just putting it all as strings, but I don't know if there might be a better way... Thanks!

Comment: you will have to use quotes for data that consists of at least one character, dates for example also need quotes when they use a separator like `-`. Numbers on the other hand need no quotes. It is really only needed when inserting data including characters. you can check the column types of your tables by using the command: show columns from your_table_name. However putting them all as strings will also work even if you are inserting a number with surrounding `'` into a number field